# How to set iTerm2 shortcut to be "dumb" selection?

Tags: shortcut, iterm

I'm mostly happy with the way double-click selection works.

There are times, though, when I would like to perform a selection that's more "dumb" (eg select based on whitespace delimiters only) and would like to bind that action to <kbd>⇧</kbd>+double-click. Is there a way to do this?

IOW, depending on the situation, I would like to be able to choose between smart and dumb selection by binding smart selection to double-click (the default), and dumb selection to <kbd>⇧</kbd>double-click.

Comment: So, are you wanting to select a word that includes the whitespace before and after the word?  Can you double click the first whitespace, then `Shift` Click, the second?  I don't think there's an Emacs keybinding that selects words in this manner.

Comment: I'm wanting to select all characters between whitespace not including the whitespace characters.

Comment: So, I guess I am confused.  When I double click on a word in iTerm, it selects that word (between the whitespaces).  Is this not the functionality you also get?  If not, what happens when you double click?

Comment: Double-click in iTerm2 is set to "smart selection" for me. That means it includes a configurable set of punctuation that will be included in selections. Other punctuation will be considered to be a separator like whitespace. What I would like is for double-click to remain "smart" in this way but for shift+double-click to be "dumb" and use only whitespace as separators.

Comment: Just checked and when I turn on Smart Selection, the configurable characters turn *off.* Maybe this is reversed on your end?  You should also include those details in the original question with an [edit].

Comment: I want to be able to perform both kinds of selections, smart selection bound to double-click and dumb selection bound to <kbd>⇧</kbd>+double-click.